# .NET CompactFramework TextBox.selectAll on gotFocus

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

i'm developing an application for an mobile device with WM 6.5 (.NET 3.5) and have the following problem:

When the textBox.gotFocus() event is called on an textBox in my form, I call the SelectAll() method of this textBox for selecting the entire text.

This method works in case of Tab navigation (selectNextControl()), but not in case of "touching" this textBox on device display.
In this case the selectAll() method is executed, but the text is not selected.

Has anyone experience with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess (and it's only a guess) is that when you tap on the text box there is a GotFocus event followed by a Click event.  When you handle the GotFocus you select all the text, but then the system behaviour for the Click event is to deselect the text.

Comment: It's quite possible. But the problem is, theres no OnClick Event in CF for textBoxes.

Comment: Indeed, though MSDN says that in the .Net CF the Click method inherits from the underlying Control class.  My .Net CF app has a textbox named 'output' and I can add this code:
`Control x = (Control)output;
x.Click += new EventHandler(myClickHandler);`
I haven't tested it but it might do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks, it was a great idea but unfortunately it doesnt work. The click event wont trigger :<

Answer (score 5):

The problem is Windows Mobile's internal event handling. Using a timer and doing the `SelectAll()` a few milliseconds after the event is triggered fixes the problem.

Just do this instead of the usual `SelectAll()` in your `GotFocus` event handler:

```
var timer = new Timer { Interval = 100, Enabled = true };
timer.Tick += (EventHandler) delegate
{
    SelectAll();
    timer.Dispose();
};
```

Comment: This is not the best solution but it works, also on other versions of .net framework.